# C#/SQL Cloud application - clients on different versions

Tags: c#, sql, cloud

I'm designing a small application for a group of users at different physical locations.  The application will connect to a central database in the cloud (well, on a central server - think cloud, but not really cloud).  The database is held centrally to facilitate backups in a central location.  I'm a seasoned developer, and the connection methods, code and other factors really aren't the issue.

However, I have a need to allow the application be upgraded to a newer version when the user sees fit - not on any kind of schedule.  In a new update, the database schema could possibly change.  So I'm going to run into the problem of User A downloading the new version, and upgrading the database.  Users B, C and D will then get errors when they try to hit the database as tables/views may not be there.

I've thought about maintaining different databases on the same server.  When User A upgrades, we'll "push" their database values to DB_V2 from DB_V1 and they'll use that one.  Users B, C & D will still be able to use DB_V1 until they decide to upgrade.  Eventually, DB_V1 can be removed when all users have upgraded away from that database.

Can I get some thoughts on the best way to handle this in a cloud-esque application?  How are DB updates normally done/handled when clients might be on different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is hard and there is no silver bullet. The name of the game is versioning, and you must support overlapping versions. Your access API must be versioned. Eg. consider the client communicates with the 'cloud' over a REST interface. The root URL for the API could be somehting like `http://example.com/api/v1.1/`. When you deploy a new version, you also move the API to `http://example.com/api/v1.2/` and expose the new features in this new API, but continue to support the old v1.1 too. you give a period of grace to clients to upgrade to v1.2, and retire v1.1 sometime int he future, after sufficient number of clients have upgraded. [The REST API Design Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00890OBFI) is a good resource on the topic.

Now the real problem is your back end, the code that sits behind the URL service. You have to carefully design each upgrade step as to maintain backward compatibility with previous version. Is very likely that both overlapping versions would use the same storage (same DB). If an user adds an item using v1.2 API he usually expects to find it using the v1.1 API later, albeit possibly missing some attributes specific to v1.2. Your back end has to decide how to handle the v1.2 attributes for items added/edited using v1.1 API (eg. default values, NULLs etc). As I said, it is hard and ther eis no silver bullet. Sometimes you may have to bite the bullet and provide no back compat (items added with v1.2 are not visible to v1.1 API clients, ie. use separate storage, different DBs).

How about the case when your client access directly the DB? Ie. there is no explicit API, the client connects directly to the database. Your chances of success have diminished significantly... You can have your interaction with the DB use an API, eg. use only stored procedures for *everything*. By using schemas as namespaces you can provide a versioning, eg. `exec [v1.1].[getProducts]` vs. `exec [v1.2].[getProducts]`. But is cumbersome, hard, error prone and you can kiss goodbye most of the dev tools wizards, orms and other whistles and bells.

Comment: Great - thank you for the response.  Just like anything else, I'm going to do my best to plan this out on paper and proofs of concept before trying it in the field.  I'd like to identify as many "gotchas" as I can before hitting production.  Thanks for the input - it was truly helpful.